# Is it usual and cutomary for seller to provide credit card debt amounts and bank accounts to title agent

Tags: real-estate, trusts-and-estates

Got an unusual one.....selling a house, from an estate, as court appointed administrator.  Title agent is asking administrator to provide the consumer credit cards and amounts, of decedent, owed to consumer credit  and a summary of medical debts to be paid.  Familiar with providing mortgage, lien amounts, ect.  Consumer credit amounts seem a bit excessive and, is that customary for an estate property sale.  Medical can theoretically have some bearing, but curious what contemporaries feel about disclosure of medical debts to buyer, buyer agents, and everyone in the chain of ownership of title documents (imagine a HIPPA violation could be a risk...)

Comment: Where? A particular U.S. state? The U.K.? Australia? HIPPA implies the U.S. but it isn't really clear as "title agent" is a phrase that is much more common in British English than in American English and not well defined in the U.S. The nature of the probate proceeding is also relevant. Usually, these are questions an estate administrator asks family because they go to priority of claims in a probate estate.

Comment: OH, decedent, not descendent. I couldn't figure out if the agent was asking about the dead person, an heir (decendant). Is the title agent asking on behalf of the escrow company? That's who I would expect to be concerned about where the sale proceeds should go and/or who will pay the costs of the "seller."

Comment: @mkennedy : yes decedent - the dead person.  title agent question pertains to the consumer debt and medical debt of the decedent.

Comment: @ohwilleke : this is in NJ usa. Well said, "title agents" are generally unregulated entities in america and stand as a major source of illegal house transfers. Hence the concern about furnishing sensitive information. Were these questions asked by the court or estate lawyer, there would be less concern, and i would probably not have even posted this question for discussion.

Comment: @debdragon  ""title agents" are generally unregulated entities in america" Title insurance companies are tightly regulated in the U.S., usually by insurance regulators. Realtors are usually also tightly regulated. I am quite suspicious that the "title agents" are legitimate in your case as unregulated title agents are actually pretty much unheard of in the U.S., although NJ probate practice is particularly arcane and they could be hoping to insure that some sort of lien for priority debts in the probate estate is not applied to a good faith purchaser whose title they insure.

Comment: Sure enough, independent title agents do exist in NJ. https://www.caare.org/independenttitles/new-jersey/ Still doubtful that this one is on the level and pretty sure that they aren't unregulated.